# Unable to update Test Execution Description and Summary using Jira XRay API

Tags: api, jira-rest-api, jira-xray

I have used Post call using this API *rest/raven/1.0/import/execution* and the body format is below to update the description in Test execution. I am getting a 200 response and also in the test execution it's showing that updated a minute ago but the description doesn't get updated :

```
{
    "testExecutionKey": "DEMO-1206",
    "info" : {
        "description" : "This execution is automatically created when importing execution results from an external source"
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the description field is not updated; only the results.
However, there's an improvement on Xray backlog to address it. Please review it and vote on it, so the team can track your interest and you can be notified upon changes on it.
https://jira.getxray.app/browse/XRAY-3915

Comment: @sumit-agarwal, was my answer able to clarify your question? If so, can you please mark my answer as correct? Otherwise, please let me know, so I can see I can help you further. Thanks